# Read a CSV from Google Cloud Storage using Google Cloud Functions in Python script

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, blob

I'm new in GCP and I'm trying to do a simple API with Cloud Functions. This API needs to read a CSV from Google Cloud Storage bucket and return a JSON. To do this, in my local I can run normally, open a file.

But in Cloud Functions, I received a blob from bucket, and don know how manipulate this, I'm receiving error

I try convert blob to Bytes and to string but i don't know exactly how do it

Code working in my local env:

```
data1 = '2019-08-20'
data1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(data1, '%Y-%m-%d')

data2 = '2019-11-21' 
data2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(data2, '%Y-%m-%d')


with open("/home/thiago/mycsvexample.csv", "r") as fin:
    #create a CSV dictionary reader object
    print(type(fin))
    csv_dreader = csv.DictReader(fin)
#iterate over all rows in CSV dict reader
    for row in csv_dreader:
        #check for invalid Date values

        #convert date string to a date object
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(row['date'], '%Y-%m-%d')
        #check if date falls within requested range
        if date >= data1 and date <= data2:
            total = total + float(row['total'])

print(total)
```

Code in Google Cloud Functions:

```
import csv, datetime
from google.cloud import storage
from io import BytesIO 

def get_orders(request):
    """Responds to any HTTP request.
    Args:
        request (flask.Request): HTTP request object.
    Returns:
        The response text or any set of values that can be turned into a
        Response object using
        `make_response <http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.make_response>`.
    """
    request_json = request.get_json()
    if request.args and 'token' in request.args:
        if request.args['token'] == 'mytoken888888':
            client = storage.Client()
            bucket = client.get_bucket('mybucketgoogle.appspot.com')

            blob = bucket.get_blob('mycsvfile.csv')
            byte_stream = BytesIO()
            blob.download_to_file(byte_stream)
            byte_stream.seek(0)
            file = byte_stream

            #with open(BytesIO(blob), "r") as fin:

                #create a CSV dictionary reader object
            csv_dreader = csv.DictReader(file)
                #iterate over all rows in CSV dict reader
            for row in csv_dreader:
                #check for invalid Date values


                date = datetime.datetime.strptime(row['date'], '%Y-%m-%d')
                    #check if date falls within requested range
                if date >= datetime.datetime.strptime(request.args['start_date']) and date <= datetime.datetime.strptime(request.args['end_date']):
                    total = total + float(row['total'])
            dict = {'total_faturado' : total}



            return dict
        else:

            return f'Passe parametros corretos'
    else:
        return f'Passe parametros corretos'
```

Error in Google Cloud Functions:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 346, in run_http_function result = _function_handler.invoke_user_function(flask.request) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 217, in invoke_user_function return call_user_function(request_or_event) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 210, in call_user_function return self._user_function(request_or_event) File "/user_code/main.py", line 31, in get_orders_tramontina for row in csv_dreader: File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/csv.py", line 111, in __next__ self.fieldnames File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/csv.py", line 98, in fieldnames self._fieldnames = next(self.reader) _csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

I try do some other things but no sucess...

Someone can help me with this blob, to convert this or manipulate with the right way?

Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code that worked for me:

```
from google.cloud import storage 
import csv


client = storage.Client()

bucket = client.get_bucket('source')

blob = bucket.blob('file')

dest_file = '/tmp/file.csv'

blob.download_to_filename(dest_file)
dict = {}
total = 0

 with open(dest_file) as fh:
    # assuming your csv is del by comma
    rd = csv.DictReader(fh, delimiter=',')
    for row in rd:
         date = datetime.datetime.strptime(row['date'], '%Y-%m-%d')
                #check if date falls within requested range
         if date >= datetime.datetime.strptime(request.args['start_date']) and date <= datetime.datetime.strptime(request.args['end_date']):
                total = total + float(row['total'])
         dict['total_faturado'] = total
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to do this too using a library gcsfs

https://gcsfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

````
def get_orders_tramontina(request):
    """Responds to any HTTP request.
    Args:
        request (flask.Request): HTTP request object.
    Returns:
        The response text or any set of values that can be turned into a
        Response object using
        `make_response <http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.make_response>`.
    """
    request_json = request.get_json()
    if request.args and 'token' in request.args:
        if request.args['token'] == 'mytoken':
            fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project='myproject')
            total = 0
            with fs.open('mybucket.appspot.com/mycsv.csv', "r") as fin:

                csv_dreader = csv.DictReader(fin)
                #iterate over all rows in CSV dict reader
                for row in csv_dreader:
                #check for invalid Date values


                    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(row['date'], '%Y-%m-%d')
                    #check if date falls within requested range
                    if date >= datetime.datetime.strptime(request.args['start_date'], '%Y-%m-%d') and date <= datetime.datetime.strptime(request.args['end_date'], '%Y-%m-%d'):
                        total = total + float(row['total'])
            dict = {'total_faturado' : total}



            return json.dumps(dict)```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try to download file as string, that way you can check for invalid data values, and eventually write that to a file.

change `blob.download_to_file(byte_stream)` to `my_blob_str = blob.download_as_string()`

I think your actual problem is `byte_stream = BytesIO()` since your output reads `iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)`

It is expecting a string, but gets bytes. What is the purpose of `byte_stream`? If random, just remove it.